# Why am I getting this error "Azure Error: InvalidTemplateDeployment"?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I am trying to create a virtual machine in Azure cli. Following is the command

```
az vm create --resource-group user-bgfbaowgiqxc --name VmName --image CentOS --admin-username azureuser --admin-password AdminPassword@1 --size Basic_A1 --generate-ssh-keys
```

I have tried changing size to Standard_B1s and standard_B1ms but still getting the same error. I have just started learning azure.

Comment: huh, template deployment? this is not a deployment

Answer (score 0):

From provided information can not make out exactly for which parameter this error had thrown. but you can use below provided ps to create VM.

1. Create resource group
2. Execute below command in azure cli (End of each command add backticks `)

   `New-AzVm`
   -ResourceGroupName "Here enter your resource group name" 
   `-Name "VM name"`
   -Location "East US" 
   `-VirtualNetworkName "VN name"`
   -SubnetName "Subnet VM" 
   `-SecurityGroupName "SG name"`
   -PublicIpAddressName "IP name" 
   `-OpenPorts 80,3389`
3. Post executing above command, CLI will prompt you to enter user name and password for VM.
4. Your VM will be ready in couple of minutes.

[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-powershell)